# How to read a cookie with react-cookie?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies

I am building a FullStack App with React and Express.
I am using react-cookie.
After submit a form i set cookies in my browser then i render a new page in my application.

```js
setCookie("jwt", `${data.jwt}`, {
  path: "/"
});
setCookie("user", `${data.name}`, {
  path: "/"
});
```

Then i want to read a cookie in that component and i do not know how can i do it.
So if someone have any idea how to do it please write below :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hook `useCookies` like this:

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookie-name']);

const myCookie = cookies.get('cookie-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use much simpler way like this
**(make sure you have installed  react-cookie FIRST!)**

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies();

// set Cookie
setCookie('access_token','your_token_value_here')

// read cookie with 
console.log(cookies.access_token)
```